# Regex expression with \1 references not matching desired string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on this regex expression and i have confusion how it is working.

```
/^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/
```

i know that

```
^ is start of line 
() shows capture group
\d+ shows digits 
\s is whitespace 
\1 shows to match first group
$ the end
```

confusing part is $ here 
and why it is matching to `"40 40 40 "`  but `not "40 40 40 40"` and role of `$`

Comment: Hint: How many `\1` instances are there? Could you make it match by adding more?

Comment: two instance because i needed to match three groups not 4 . i am having issues how it works :)

Comment: @Amadan  are you saying $ is "nothing else " here

Comment: Pretty much, yes. As you said, it is "end of string" (or "end of line", depending on the `m` flag), and `^` is "beginning of string" (or line). The pattern says there shall be three identical things sandwiched from start to end of string, with some spaces between them. If you omitted `$`, then `"40 40 40foo"` would find a match. If you omitted `^`, then `foo40 40 40"` would. If you omit both, `"foo40 40 40foo"` would be okay. If you want three groups, and `"40 40 40 40"` is being rejected, then it's all as it should be, no?

Comment: completely got it now usage of ^ and $ was confusing for me now i got it thank You .it is all .it is a challenge in FCC . you are awesome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\1` refers to the first capturing group in the regular expression. `\2` will refer to the second capturing group and \n will refer to an nth capturing group.

In the regular expression `/^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/`. `\1` will match the only group of digits which is matched by the first capturing group `(\d+)`.

`$` in `/^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/` Means it should end by one more digits.

`^` in `/^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/` Means it should start by one more digits.

Comment: and ^ means it should start with a  digit?

Comment: Exactly @Maria you are right.  anything after `^` should be the start of the match in regular expression.

Comment: like ^\s means start of line should be space ? got it thank You

Comment: `\s` means any whitespace which includes space also. You can check characters contained in `\s` over here https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for pointing out that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$` matches "end of string". The way you have the regex pattern defined, it shouldn't match either of your strings because `40 40 40` has an extra space at the end before the end of string and `40 40 40 40` has extra space and digits after the third `40` and before the end of string.

If you remove the `$`, then it will match both of your strings or any string that begins with `40 40 40`, so for example it will also match `40 40 40 test`.

Comment: you are right i tried that :) sorry dont have enough rep to upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the answer for this challenge as /^(\d+)(\s)\1\2\1$/g and it worked. If I'm correct, the first \1 will produce (number, space, number). The \2 will add the space making it (number, space, number, space). The final \1 adds the last number, making it (number\s number\s number). The ^ and $ start and end the regex.